# Can I have a user preference for the ISO 8601 standard date format for all dates/times?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown

I'd really like an option to show all dates as yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm. The existing multitude of various things based on the age is much less workable.

Probably, at least the three common formats for date are needed with a check box for 2/4 digit year and a character for the separator, including no character at all:

```
yy-mm-dd
dd-mm-yy
mm-dd-yy
```

along with the time formats:

```
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
HH:mm xM
HH:mm:ss xM
```

(where the x is either A or P).

Comment: Commonly, this is called `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

Comment: @Peter, yes I mean 8601.

Comment: Yes, please. To me, a date such as "Jan 14 '10" looks quite ugly.  As has been remarked on related questions, most of the world does not use the illogical M/D/Y date display system. As we are all nerds, you'd think that the ISO 8601 standard would be favoured among us: alphabetical order equal numerical order equals chronological order. Please, at least make it possible for users to customize it as an option for displaying dates. Please, please, please.

Comment: If we regressed and now use a different format, please post a new bug report.

Comment: @Anna: I am not sure I understand your ***if*** in "if we regressed", which makes me question whether the request is understood; clearly one can view any question or answer and the "asked" or "answered" date everywhere is the ugly and hard to read and very *American* style like "Jan 13 '10 at 3:01" style (I particularly abhor the `'10`. Contrary to Jeff's "answer" it does not and never has displayed the ISO format date/time for "for anything older than 2 days".  I fear if I raise this again it will quickly be closed as a duplicate, which is why I ask that the status-completed be removed.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey We don't remove "status-completed" from old bugs that may have reoccurred. The screenshots Jeff posted make it look like the tooltips at least are showing the correct format. I don't recall off-hand if the username box on posts did the same back in 2010 or not. It's best to post a new, more specific bug report that just addresses that part or a feature request that asks for the format to be changed. (For what it's worth, I don't find the current style harder to read than the ISO even when I wear my not-American hat, but we'll see where the community opinion lands on that one.)

Comment: This question is 4 years old. The system has changed a lot since then, so editing this post is not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @Anna: Jeffs answer states, and I quote, "for anything older than 2 days, show the ISO date" (not in the tooltip, but in the page body). This has never been true, so it's not a regression - Jeff wrongly marked this status-completed at the outset (and I complained to him about that at the time) as you can see in the comments.

Comment: I'm on your side here. :) My advice is to make a new request and let it be vetted by other users instead of reusing this old post.

Comment: @Anna: Done; wanna make friendly wager on how fast it's closed as a duplicate? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The current algorithm is

- for anything newer than 2 days old, show relative time with the ISO tooltip (screenshot below)
- for anything older than 2 days, show the ISO date

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/9750/datecursortooltiphover.png

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn circles.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: what has been changed? Where is the option to show all dates in ISO format? Or does it now always show in ISO format? Or isn't there any change?

Comment: @Jeff: I don't want to have to hover to see a standard date/time format; I want a user option to always show it.

Comment: @Jeff: I am curious - why the (apparently) bull-headed resistance to this request? I am not the first user to object to the current date/time stamping - it seems a common complaint.  Surely it can't be that hard to just give us yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm time stamps!

Comment: This question should be marked rejected, not completed - it wasn't completed, since what I asked for was to display the ISO date (without requiring hovering) *instead* of "today", etc, as a user option.

Comment: The image link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox there's also [a GreaseMonkey script that does this](https://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time).

Note: the script has two configuration options, you will have to edit them to get the behavior you want. It's documented on the question I linked above.

Comment: Sorry - Chrome.

Comment: The link to the stackexchange article has changed: http://stackapps.com/questions/2528/display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time

Also the link to the script on userscripts has changed: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/62146

Just started using it in Fx and it works marvelously.