# Date of question answered, current year in the 'YY format, ie '14 for 2014

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask for an improvement in the stackoverflow site etc.

This is the case; answered questions get a date tag when the question was answered.

When there is an old question for an framework like jQuery, for example from 2010 there are often many answers. Often somone comes up with an much smarter solution years later. Often the most recent answer is the best since someone made an effort to make another answer to a most of the time already answered question.

I always seek for the answers that are as current as possible if it's an old question - I often end up on these questions when googling for different programing issues.

Therefore it would be fantastic if the output showed the current year so I can hit "find on page" in my browser and fast see the latest answers. Today if it's answered this year, the year isn't shown so it isn't searchable on the page.

"answered Jan 21 '12 at 4:41" since it's a previous year ... '12 is searchable for that years answers

"answered Jan 21 at 4:41" if it's this year ...  is not so searchable for this years answers

"answered Jan 21 **'14** at 4:41" if it's this year  ... '14 is searchable for this years answers and this is the suggested format. Just adding that **14'**, or **'YY**.

So I guess my question is, wouldnt that be an easy improvement?

Thanks for a greeeeeeat web community.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have a user preference for ISO standard date format for all dates/times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35368/can-i-have-a-user-preference-for-iso-standard-date-format-for-all-dates-times)

Comment: Mouse over the date, the tooltip shows the ISO date including the year.

Comment: Why not just sort the answers by "oldest" and then look at the last one?

Comment: Not really a dupe, this is just about adding year to the existing format in all 'answered' and 'edited' lines, not a checkbox to use ISO date formatting.

Comment: ... ehum a bit embarrasing. I have used the site for years and never really noticed the sort oldest tab. But at the same time I quite like to search on pages with a keyboard shortcut :) Maybe I should delete this suggestion?